# mysql twitter/facebook like status feed

Tags: mysql, facebook, select, twitter, status

I have two tables. One named `status` like this...

```
user_id |  status
--------+-----------
      1 |  random status from user 1
      2 |  random status from user 2
      3 |  random message from user 3
      4 |  staus from user 4 
      1 |  second status for user1
```

etc...
and another named `users_following` like this...

```
user_id |  is_following
--------+-----------
      1 |  2
      1 |  3
      2 |  1
      3 |  2
```

meaning that user `1` is following both users `2` and `3` etc...

So, let's say I chose user `1`.  What is the best query (performance wise) to show the status updates of users that user `1` is following, in this case users `2` and `3`

currently I have something like

```
SELECT * from status WHERE user_id IN(SELECT is_following FROM users_following 
WHERE user_id='1') LIMIT 0,5
```

but I don't think this is good for performance if a user was following thousands+ of users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You forgot `ORDER BY date_posted DESC` (or `status_id`)
2. `INNER JOIN` would be better here

   ```
       SELECT s.*
         FROM status s
   INNER JOIN users_following f ON f.is_following = s.user_id
                               AND f.user_id = 1
     ORDER BY s.status_id DESC
        LIMIT 0, 5
   ```

**Notes**
1. There is no single quotes around integer `1`
2. You should create composite index `user_id + is_following`

Comment: yeah, I have the `order by` but I just didn't think it was that necessary for the question.. So, how would you implement the INNER JOIN into it?

Comment: Wow, thanks. looks like its working great. So, do you think this will work good, if a user subscribed to thousands+ of users.

Comment: Thanks man, I tested it on one of my tables with 4mil+ rows and it works perfect.